# What format timestamp is this in PHP and why can't i convert it using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

This API i am using returns a timestamp in the format below. It is only explained as "timestamp in UTC" in their docs. I can not figure out what format this is, or how to convert it using javascript. I have tried using new Date(), moment.js, and everything in-between. Can anyone explain how to do this in JS instead of PHP?

```
// timestamp from api
20200430094700
```

using Javascript, i always get something way off like:

```
Friday, February 16, 2610 6:34:54.700 AM
```

Here i will use PHP to convert it to a correct unix timestamp and a date object

```
$timestamp = 20200430094700;

$e = new DateTime($timestamp);

// This is the correct Unix timestamp
// 1588258020
echo date_timestamp_get($e);        

// This is the correct date
// [date] => 2020-04-30 09:47:00.000000
print_r($e);
```

Comment: Hint: `20200430094700` -> `2020 04 30 09 47 00` and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, `20200430094700` is not a timestamp but a date in the format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. To convert that into a `Date` in JavaScript, you need to extract the component parts (using e.g. [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)), subtract one from the month to make it a JS month (indexed from 0) and then pass that into [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) and use its output in the `Date` constructor:

```js
const ts = '20200430094700';

const d = new Date(Date.UTC(ts.slice(0,4), ts.slice(4,6)-1, ts.slice(6,8), ts.slice(8,10), ts.slice(10,12), ts.slice(12,14)));
console.log(d);
```